# In a Core Data entity, how do I use a source entity's attribute in its fetched property's predicate?

Tags: iphone, core-data, fetch, predicate

I am using the visual editor for creating a Core Data model. I can't figure out how to set a fetched property's predicate so that it uses the source entity's attributes in the predicate.

For example, I have `EntityA` with an attribute `searchId`. I also have `EntityB` with an attribute `id`. What I want to do is find all instances of `EntityB` whose `id` is equal to `EntityA`'s `searchId` atrribute. When I try to edit the predicate, the drop-down list for the left-hand side and right-hand side only contain the keys for the destination, which in this case is `EntityB`, and no way to select any key from `EntityA`.

I know that you can just create the predicate programmatically, but I was wondering if there's a way to do it using the visual editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit of a pain.

First, in the predicate editor control click in the empty space to the right of the predicate's last field and select "`variable`".Then enter "`FETCH_SOURCE.attributeName`" in the field.

FETCH_SOURCE (or $FETCH_SOURCE in code) is a special variable that indicates the object originating the fetch for the fetched property. There is also FETCHED_PROPERTY ($FETCHED_PROPERTY) which will return the actual NSFetchedPropertyDescription object.

So, your predicate would in text look like:

```
id==$FETCH_SOURCE.searchId
```

Apple is apparently not very proud of this functionality because they have buried any references to it deep in the mythic catacombs of Cupertino. It took me four days to figure it out the first time.

Comment: any idea how to do it in XCode4?

Comment: `Editor>Add FetchRequest` gives you the visual editor. I haven't used it yet.

Comment: They are refered at the bottom of `Core Data programming Guide` on `Relationships and Fetched Properties` chapter : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html